# Using a resource within Protected Sub

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using ASP.NET to code a web form and I am working with protected sub classes for the first time.  I am very used to using normal classes in c# and java and have been working with Sql-Server projects along with it.

Usually I would create the Connection String (Sql-Server) as a String within the resources meaning that when I would need to use the connection string I would only have to do something like this

```
SqlDataAdapter(String1, Properties.Resources.ConnectionString)
```

Now that I am working with protected sub classes in ASP.NET, how would I go about accessing my resources and retrieving the string? I am very new to ASP.NET so sorry if I seem vague.
I have been researching for hours for an answer, thanks in advance

Comment: Put the string in the Web.config and access it via the ConfigurationManager.

Comment: Could you show me an example of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using resources, use the Web.config file, like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DATABASE;User Id=USER;Password=PWD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In code, use ConfigurationManager:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString
```

More information on Microsoft Docs:

[Using external configuration files for storing connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#example-retrieving-a-connection-string-by-name)

[Retrieving a connection string by name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#example-retrieving-a-connection-string-by-name)